# How can I solve two errors adding "?useUnicode"?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am connecting to a MySQL database but I got an error about timezone. So I solved it by adding `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`:

```java
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db_isim + 
 "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
```

Now I need to add this too: `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8`

Is there a way for this?
(Not very good at English so basic explanation or just the code will be good)

I need to add this code for Turkish characters. I tried adding next to it but the connection went lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db_isim 
                + "?useUnicode=true&"
                + "useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&"
                + "useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&"
                + "serverTimezone=UTC&"
                + "characterEncoding=utf8";
```

Comment: Okay I realised need to add _&_ and then do the different coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**You can type the code in the following format and if you encounter a problem in the connection make sure the variables used within the code or make sure to add jdbc library**

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db_isim + "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
```